# Expanded objects key in chrome console now unsorted

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

So for example: prior Chrome 78 (or 79) after expanding some JS object in console all it's keys were sorted alphabetically. In current version there is no sort at all. I can understand why they removed it but I can't find any info about or setting to restore previous behavior. Sometimes it's nice to sorted keys, especially in giant objects.

[Expanded object with unsorted keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR8cy.jpg)

Comment: You can't restore it. They will be [sorted again](https://crbug.com/989514#c18) in Chrome 81, currently Canary. Well, technically you can [edit devtools source code](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/devtools/devtools-frontend/+/1969479/5/front_end/object_ui/ObjectPropertiesSection.js) inside `resources.pak` file, it's not exactly rocket science...